# How to correctly configure PHP settings on Zabbix installation?

Tags: rhel7, zabbix-agent

I'm currently installing [Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/introduction/about) on RedHat Enterprise Linux 7. I'm stuck at PHP configuration. [Here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/installation/install_from_packages/rhel_centos#zabbix_frontend_and_server_on_rhel_6) you can see all PHP configurations required for Zabbix. Running `cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/zabbix.conf` I discovered all configurations are OK. But when I enter `http://myServerIP/zabbix` I get errors about PHP configurations not as required. As example, it says

Minimum required size of PHP post is 16M (configuration option "post_max_size").

But when I ran `cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/zabbix.conf | grep 'post_max_size'` I get 16M. Is there any visible step that I maybe skipped? I already restarted httpd service, so I don't know why this is not working

Comment: `/etc/httpd/` only contains the apache configuration, not your php configuration. it is possible that your PHP configuration does not allow the values to be set in the apache config.

Comment: I went to `/etc/php.ini` and found all the wrong values showed at `http://myServerIP/zabbix`. Could you state your comment as an answer to accept? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/httpd/` only contains the Apache configuration, not your PHP configuration. it is possible that your PHP configuration does not allow the values to be set in the Apache config.

Check your `/etc/php.ini` and set your desired values there.

Comment: This does not work for me. Even though I have edited /etc/php.ini (properly I am sure), the preinstallation web page does not seem to recognize the changes.

Comment: @TimothyPulliam in that case you should ask a new question and include your configuration files. This is not going to be answered in the comments.

Comment: I figured it out. Every time I change php.ini I need to restart httpd.